# how to add Auth::Basic to simple Rack application

Tags: ruby, rack

how can I add this

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
  username == 'pippo' && password == 'pluto'
end
```

to this

```
class HelloWorld
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    case req.path_info
    when /badges/
      [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"},  ['This is great !!!!']]
    when /goodbye/
      [500, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Goodbye Cruel World!"]]
    else
      [404, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["I'm Lost!"]]
    end
  end
end


run HelloWorld.new
```

I have this simple Rack application and I need to add Auth::Basic.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Rack::Builder to compose a stack of rack applications.

Example:

```
# app.ru
require 'rack'

class HelloWorld
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    case req.path_info
    when /badges/
      [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"},  ['This is great !!!!']]
    when /goodbye/
      [500, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["Goodbye Cruel World!"]]
    else
      [404, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["I'm Lost!"]]
    end
  end
end

app = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    username == 'pippo' && password == 'pluto'
  end

  map '/' do
    run HelloWorld.new
  end
end

run app
```

And to start it up:

```
$ rackup app.ru
```

Comment: Now in 2024 Rack::Lint requires all Headers to be lowcased so "Content-Type" should be "content-type"